# Battery drain rate,for server calls in regular intervals

Tags: android, performance, push-notification

Hi iam currently working on a hotel notifier android application.Which gives the users a listview of hotels around them.It updates this list and notifies them whenever a new hotel is around them.The app should notify the user in the status bar with the name of the hotels when the user reaches near to these hotels.
Please tell me how can i implement this technique.
Can I use something like checking whether the users current location is near to the location of the hotels whose details are stored in a table called "hotels" within certain intervals(say every 5 minutes it checks whether any new hotel is around user's location if found it would notify the user in the status bar.
But does this process drain out a lot of battery....?
If yes ,then some one could please suggest me some other method.
any help would be apprciable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refresh the location every 30 mins/1 hour and keep a radius of 50-70km.

Keep displaying the hotels with their distance (in kms). 
If hotel A is at 3km away when the person is at point 1. Then after 30 mins when you refresh he may have reached point 2 which is 4km away from the hotel.